# Change keyboard shortcuts in RAD Studio 2010

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, c++builder, delphi-2010, c++builder-2010

I use C++ Builder 2010 and I could'nt figure out how to change keyboard shortcuts.

From Tools > Options > Editor Options > Key Mappings, there are some key mapping modules, I use "IDE classic module", but I want to change some shortcuts in this module, is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. It is a top requested feature to be able to customize them.

Comment: Is there no file you can edit for this? Like a .pas or something?

Comment: I haven't used any recent XE versions, but as of XE2 or so it wasn't possible.

Comment: There is no way to add a shortcut for a menu item?!
I have added a new external tool to the RAD Studio and want to define a shortcut for that. Any idea?

Comment: I just dont understand why they would map Ctrl+w to such a weird and illogical feature. Even in rad studio 10.4 - STILL,..

Answer (score 5):

[GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) plugin allows you to change "IDE Menu Shortcuts", from the menu item with such name.